# How do I join my result to retrieve another table's corresponding records?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

```
(SELECT BOOKAUTHOR from (select DISTINCT bookauthor, genre from BOOK) group by bookauthor HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

So confused about joins

please let me know if there is anyway to improve my question, i have tried to search and search and am still so confused to make this happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do something like

```
SELECT a.AUTHORFIRSTNAME,
       a.AUTHORLASTNAME
  FROM (SELECT BOOKAUTHOR, COUNT(*)
          FROM BOOK
          GROUP BY BOOKAUTHOR
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b
  INNER JOIN AUTHOR a
    ON a.AUTHORID = b.BOOKAUTHOR
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9498906f009f39c0318d6ddc993816de)

Comment: Hi @basilgoops1 , you can try to accept the answer if it helped.